# Error when building TensorFlow

Tags: build, tensorflow

I'm trying to build `TensorFlow` with this command :

```
sudo bazel build -c opt --local_resources 1024,1.0,1.0 --verbose_failures --copt="-mfpu=neon" tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

But I get this error : http://pastebin.com/VvczWkmM

EDIT : I found a way to solve this, but now I get this error : http://pastebin.com/zUfP4xsP

Answer (score 0):

Fixed !
If someone has the same problem, that's how I solved it : I had to edit the `tensorflow/core/platform/jpeg.h` file to force the `#include` by removing the `#elif` condition and replacing it by a normal `#else`.